# LonglistSelector binding to Image Collection does not display

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, binding, longlistselector

I have a xaml page. xaml page wants to show two TextBlocks and one LonglistSelector.

the two TextBlocks datasource come from an object(SpecifiedArticle);the LonglistSelctor itemsSource comes from Collection(ImageUriCollection).

when the page launch, the images cannot be displayed.

1. two TextBlocks data show well
2. LonglistSelctor  does not show images; but i am sure ImageUriCollection's data can be get from the xaml because i tested in a image control and it works

   ```
           <Image  Source="{Binding ImageUriCollection[0].ImageSource}" Width="108" Height="108" Stretch="UniformToFill">


           </Image>
   ```

i think the issue is in the LonglistSelctor  itemsSource binding. anyone can help?

all code below(without the httpclient wrapper):

DetailsPage.cs is below:

```
public partial class DetailsPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        DetailsPageViewModel viewModel = new DetailsPageViewModel();

        public DetailsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(DetailsPage_Loaded);
        }

        private void DetailsPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = viewModel;
            //imageList.ItemsSource = viewModel.ImageUriCollection;
            //imageList.ScrollTo(imageList.ItemsSource[imageList.ItemsSource.Count - 1]);
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            string ArticleId = "";
            try
            {
                if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("ArticleId", out ArticleId))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ArticleId);
                    viewModel.LoadPage(Int32.Parse(ArticleId));
                    //Debug.WriteLine(viewModel.SpecifiedArticle.Words.ToString());
                    //LayoutRoot.DataContext = new CollectionViewSource { Source = viewModel.SpecifiedArticle };
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No ArticleId passed in.");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in DetailsPage.OnNavigatedTo"); 
            }
        }
    }
```

ViewModel is below:

```
public class DetailsPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isLoading = false;

        public bool IsLoading
        {
            get
            {
                return _isLoading;
            }
            set
            {
                _isLoading = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsLoading");
            }
        }

        public DetailsPageViewModel()
        {
            this.SpecifiedArticle = new Article();
            this.ImageUriCollection = new ObservableCollection<Photo>();
            this.IsLoading = false;
        }

        private Article specifiedArticle;
        public Article SpecifiedArticle
        {
            get
            {
                return specifiedArticle;
            }
            set
            {
                specifiedArticle = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SpecifiedArticle");
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Photo> ImageUriCollection
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public void LoadPage(int articleId)
        {            
            IsLoading = true;

            ReadArticle(articleId);

        }

        private async void ReadArticle(int articleId)
        {
            try
            {
                Article articleDetails = new Article();
                articleDetails = await CollectionHttpClient.GetAsyncByArticleId(articleId);
                SpecifiedArticle = articleDetails;
                //articleDetails.FirstImage = new Uri(articleDetails.ImagePathList[0]);

                if (articleDetails.ImagePathList != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in articleDetails.ImagePathList)
                    {
                        Photo p = new Photo();
                        p.ImageSource = new Uri(item);
                        this.ImageUriCollection.Add(p);
                    }
                    //var image = await CollectionHttpClient.GetImageByImageName(articleDetails.ImagePath);
                    //Bytelist.Add(image);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.ImageUriCollection = null;
                }

                IsLoading = false;


            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("sorry, no data.");
                IsLoading = false;
            }

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
```

xaml is:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

        <vm:DetailsPageViewModel x:Key="viewModel"/>
        <phone:JumpListItemBackgroundConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter"/>
        <phone:JumpListItemForegroundConverter x:Key="ForegroundConverter"/>

        <Style x:Key="JumpListStyle" TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
            <Setter Property="LayoutMode" Value="List" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="12,12,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}" 
                                Width="470" 
                                Height="70" 
                                Margin="6">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"
                                       Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ForegroundConverter}}"                                       
                                       FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"
                                       FontSize="28"  
                                       Padding="2"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupHeader">
            <Border Background="Transparent">
                <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1"  
                        Width="400" Height="90"                  
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBlock Text="Pictures:" 
                               Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" 
                               FontSize="28"
                               Padding="2"                                
                               FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Height="108" Width="108" Margin="6,6">
                <Image Width="108" Height="108" Stretch="UniformToFill">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImageSource}" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation"/>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>


    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SpecifiedArticle.Subject }" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>

        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place images here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent">

            <!--
            <Image  Source="{Binding ImageUriCollection[0].ImageSource}" Width="108" Height="108" Stretch="UniformToFill">

                    <Image.Source>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImageSource}" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation"/>
                    </Image.Source>

            </Image>
 -->

            <phone:LongListSelector Name="imageList" Margin="13,-30,0,0"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding ImageUriCollection}"
                                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"                     

                                        JumpListStyle="{StaticResource JumpListStyle}" 
                                        IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                                        LayoutMode="Grid" 
                                        GridCellSize="108,108"/>

        </Grid>

        <!--ContentPanel - place article words here-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Margin="12,17,0,28">

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SpecifiedArticle.Words}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>



    </Grid>
```

DetailsPage.cs is below:

```
public partial class DetailsPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        DetailsPageViewModel viewModel = new DetailsPageViewModel();

        public DetailsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(DetailsPage_Loaded);
        }

        private void DetailsPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataContext = viewModel;
            //imageList.ItemsSource = viewModel.ImageUriCollection;
            //imageList.ScrollTo(imageList.ItemsSource[imageList.ItemsSource.Count - 1]);
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            string ArticleId = "";
            try
            {
                if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("ArticleId", out ArticleId))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ArticleId);
                    viewModel.LoadPage(Int32.Parse(ArticleId));
                    //Debug.WriteLine(viewModel.SpecifiedArticle.Words.ToString());
                    //LayoutRoot.DataContext = new CollectionViewSource { Source = viewModel.SpecifiedArticle };
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No ArticleId passed in.");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in DetailsPage.OnNavigatedTo"); 
            }
        }
    }
```

ViewModel is below:

```
public class DetailsPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _isLoading = false;

        public bool IsLoading
        {
            get
            {
                return _isLoading;
            }
            set
            {
                _isLoading = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsLoading");
            }
        }

        public DetailsPageViewModel()
        {
            this.SpecifiedArticle = new Article();
            this.ImageUriCollection = new ObservableCollection<Photo>();
            this.IsLoading = false;
        }

        private Article specifiedArticle;
        public Article SpecifiedArticle
        {
            get
            {
                return specifiedArticle;
            }
            set
            {
                specifiedArticle = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SpecifiedArticle");
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Photo> ImageUriCollection
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        public void LoadPage(int articleId)
        {            
            IsLoading = true;

            ReadArticle(articleId);

        }

        private async void ReadArticle(int articleId)
        {
            try
            {
                Article articleDetails = new Article();
                articleDetails = await CollectionHttpClient.GetAsyncByArticleId(articleId);
                SpecifiedArticle = articleDetails;
                //articleDetails.FirstImage = new Uri(articleDetails.ImagePathList[0]);

                if (articleDetails.ImagePathList != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in articleDetails.ImagePathList)
                    {
                        Photo p = new Photo();
                        p.ImageSource = new Uri(item);
                        this.ImageUriCollection.Add(p);
                    }
                    //var image = await CollectionHttpClient.GetImageByImageName(articleDetails.ImagePath);
                    //Bytelist.Add(image);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.ImageUriCollection = null;
                }

                IsLoading = false;


            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("sorry, no data.");
                IsLoading = false;
            }

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is the style problem.

delete the style, try again, images show well

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="imageList" Margin="13,-30,0,0" 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding ImageUriCollection}"
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
                                    LayoutMode="Grid"
                                    GridCellSize="108,108">

            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

in the JumpListStyle, it contains the textblock which is not belong to the xaml, that is why the LonglistSelector does not display anything after binding collectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

just change your ItemTemplate DataTemplate to a simpler one

If it works, add one change at a time.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: @max can you see the list being populated at all?? I mean are there any items in the list?

Comment: yes, i m sure, there are items in the list. As i said, if i remove longlistselector, i use image alone, it is good and can get the binding data.  and when i use longlistselector and put image control in the longlistselector, it fails

Comment: @max I was talking about the LongListSelector being populated, check this -> ItemsSource="{Binding ImageUriCollection}" for the LongListSelector by changing it and also check it by changing the above datatemplate to contain some other visible element such as textblock with some fix text so that if the LongListSelector populates, you can see that there is only problem in the binding

Comment: even i set <TextBlock Text="12345656" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/> in the DataTemplate, it shows nothing, seems longlistselector's problem,  do u have any other idea?